# Does the retina (or other high res.) displays affects the differentiation between phones and tablets based on resolution?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, web

I made two different webpages for the same site: one for phone devices and one for desktop devices. The primary reason is because the webpage has a lot of buttons and if you are using a phone the buttons are dificult to touch because they looks very small on phone screens. So I made a javscript who redirects the user to the respective page based on the resolution of the screen.

```
if ( (screen.width < 800) && (screen.height < 600) ) { 
    window.location = 'mobilesite';
} else {
    window.location = 'desktopsite';
}
```

But i am worried about the new retina displays. I think this approach is not going to work. (I have not a retina display device to test it)

I decide not to use a differentiation based on the operating system because my problem is with the size, not with the OS, for example, in Android/IOS/Kindle/etc. tablets I prefer the users to use the  desktop version because it looks better in big screens.

So I have two questions:
1.- The resolution of the retina display affects the resolution of the browser? (Or maybe only the native aplications)

2.- Is there any different way to diferentiate between a phone and a tablet using javascript or jquery clientside?

Also, I think is important not to limit the script to detect this diference in IOS devices only, very soon it will be more high resolution displays in phones of other brands.

Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that "retina display" is a brand name used by Apple? It just seems somewhat off to see that term used regarding Android development.

Comment: Yes, retina display changes the resolution of the whole device (it's just a higher-res screen, it's nothing fancy, really.) I'd make a tentative suggestion to redirect based on the user agent string (via PHP, to be honest) instead of screen size.

Comment: @TedHopp yes, thanks for the aclaration. I edited the title

Comment: @Eric, are not the useragents exactly the same on android devices in tablets and phones? If not it will be very useful for me

Comment: @yenssen No, my user agent string on Chrome (Galaxy Nexus) says "Linux Android 4.1.2 Galaxy Nexus". On my laptop, it says "Windows NT 6.1". They do both say Chrome (v18 and 23 respectively), which may also be helpful, since the stock browser would not say this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Apple Retina Screen will report itself as if it has half the amount of pixels it actually has, because the browser does magic itself. If you want to detect a high-res screen, multiply by the pixeldensity.

Don't do a useragent check, because you'll be adding more devices every 2 weeks. And its breaking the web. Do feature checks or specific checks.

Oh, and you'll want to read into CSS3 Media Queries, in case you just want to show bigger buttons for mobile devices.

Comment: but using this:
@ media all and (max-device-width: 480px)
am I not going to have the same problem?

Comment: Regarding media queries, [this blog](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) may be helpful.